# Dimensional Analysis help

Tags: dimensional-analysis

So a few people have tried explaining how to do dimensional analysis to me and I think I may understand how to but I am not 100% sure.

[Unsolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NFUP.png)

This is what I belive is correct

[My Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gatMa.png)

[Full Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6qyu.png)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You have the pressure $p$ as having dimensions of $M/L$, which is not correct. So I'd advise reviewing what you know about pressure.

Comment: @Harry You are dealing with an expression that sums pressure, kinetic, and potential energy of a certain system, e.g  flowing fluids. It appears in the Bernoulli Equation for the conservation of energy principle. This expression depicts the total energy of a system. Such expressions must be dimensionally balanced, i.e. each term of the expression has the same dimension. If you look at your answer, you will notice that it is not dimensionally balanced. In fact, the dimensions of all three terms are wrong. Each of these terms must have the dimension $ML^{-1}T^{-2}$.